# Metric (total-cost) not minimized with Metric-FF

Tags: planning, pddl

I'm trying to use Metric-FF (v2.1) to solve a classical planning problem. I noticed that my plans weren't optimal and started to play around with cost minimization. I realized that the planner doesn't seem to take the cost into consideration despite the cost-minimization being activated. 
I've created the following **minimal example**, with one predicate and two identical methods (besides their cost):

```
(define (domain metrictest)
    (:requirements :strips :action-costs)
    (:predicates (done ?x))

    (:functions (total-cost) - number)

    (:action do1
        :parameters (?x)
        :precondition (not (done ?x))
        :effect (and (done ?x) (increase (total-cost) 1))
    )

    (:action do2
        :parameters (?x)
        :precondition (not (done ?x))
        :effect (and (done ?x) (increase (total-cost) 5))
    )
)
```

And all I want to solve is:

```
(define (problem problem_1)
    (:domain metrictest)
    (:objects foo)
    (:init (= (total-cost) 0))
    (:goal (forall (?t) (done ?t)))
    (:metric minimize (total-cost))
)
```

Which results in **do2** to be called despite **do1** being the cheaper operation. If I change their position in the domain file, do1 is picked.

If you know any obtainable planner solving this correctly, I'd be happy use it.

Comment: As Metric-FF is over 13 years old already, I found out that "fast downward" (see www.fast-downward.org) is capable of minimizing the total cost correctly. While this does not answer why Metric-FF isn't capable of solving these kind of problems, it provides a working alternative.